# chrome stopped listen to xdotool bindings after system update

Tags: linux, bash, google-chrome, archlinux

After I ran `pacman -Syyu`, running:

`xdotool search --onlyvisible  --name 'Chrome' windowfocus key "ctrl+f"`

command got broken.

The thing is it finds chrome window correctly - it gets focused, and if it gets focused on text input field - after running upper command it types f into it. So it looks like chrome somehow strips control out of xdotool key command. The same thing with all other chrome commands.
If I type control+f manually while focused on chrome window, it works as it should, so this is not the problem with chrome shortcuts changed.
All this happened after yesterdays system update, anyone knows what could cause such behavior? thx.